# Rails accessing json object in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
var errorList = "<%= object.errors.messages.to_json %>";
```

In the above code object.errors.messages stores the Hash value as shown below.

```
{ 
  :username => [
    "can't be blank", 
    "is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"
  ],
  :first_name => [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  :last_name => [
    "can't be blank"
  ], 
  :email => [
    "can't be blank",
    "is invalid"
  ],
  :secondary_email => [ 
    "can't be blank",
    "is invalid",
    "has already been taken"
  ],
  :password => [ 
    "can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

I want to access this hash value in javascript as a json object so that i can access each error messages conveniently (for ex errorList.username, errorList.first_name etc).So i am trying to convert that hash value into json and assign it to the errorList variable.So that i can access the error messages(for ex errorList.username, errorList.first_name etc).

```
<%= object.errors.messages.to_json %>" /*here i am trying to convert hash value into json
```

But i am not able to do that using above code, tell me the errors in that code if any, Otherwise tell me how can i access the hash value in ruby as a json in javascript.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the json as a string, javascript has no idea it is json. Also, the string is not html_safe, so ruby will try to escape it. You need to tell rails it is safe and parse it:

```
var errorList = JSON.parse("<%= object.errors.messages.to_json.html_safe %>");
```

However this is not the best way to do this. There is a very nice gem called [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). It allows you to pass ruby variables to your javascript easily and will move this logic from your view to your controller.

```
# controller
gon.errorList = object.errors.messages

# javascript
gon.errorList      #=> {"username": ["can't be blank", ....], ...}
```

Comment: `it is not working` is not a proper error description. Could you please giv more details on what is the desired result and what you're getting instead?

Comment: sorry, i didnt see your comment, i used                              var errorList = <%=object.errors.messages.to_json.html_safe %>;

Comment: sorry, i didnt see your comment, i used                              var errorList = <%=object.errors.messages.to_json.html_safe %>;        i just removed doublequotes and JSON.parse which was around the ruby code.So i successfully assigned json to errorList, now i can access the errors using errorList["username"] or errorList.username.